# Sharepoint Solution with some features

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My context : I have a project (Sharepoint 2010) which contains some Features, called A, B and a new feature called C :

- the Feature A has a WepApplication scope
- the Feature B has a Web scope
- the Feature C has a Web scope

Before I added the new feature C, my solution has been deployed on my all web applications. Today, I added a new feature C. To deploy this new solution, have I to uninstall the old solution? If I have to uninstall, i'm gonna loose my feature B on the webs, so i should enable the feature B on the web?

What is the best practise? Maybe, I have to create an another solution just for my feature C?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i recall if you undelpoy a solution yet not deactivate at any point feature B, you will not lose it.